# I want to open the android camera without saving the picture to gallery

Tags: java, android, adt

[image: Screenshot]

I want the picture to go straight to the ImageView without saving it to gallery if possible. As shown in the screenshot, it will ask to save everytime and will save straight to the gallery. Can this be achieved, or will I have to make my own ImageView camera?

```
public class Main extends Activity {

ImageView ivPhoto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ivPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPic);
}

public void TakePhoto(View v){
    Intent camIntent = new      Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(camIntent,0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==0){
        Bitmap camImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(camImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: for that you have to use camera in your in apps. using intent you cannot do this.

Comment: you can use this code also.. https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/39/using__the_camera_api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding you don't want this to be showing up by any media scanner, like the gallery application. What you should actually do is not store it in a root directory like pictures or sdcard, but store it in your applications data folder in the sdcard in `Android/data/package/`.

You can get this using: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

```
File myFilesDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
```

OR

```
File myFilesDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Note that it will only work on API versions 8 or above.

If you don't want to use the function you can simply just use:

```
File myFilesDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/" + packageName + "/files");
myFilesDir.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 6):

Finally got what I wanted. Thanks guys

```
public class Main extends Activity {

ImageView ivPhoto;
File myFilesDir;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ivPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPic);
    myFilesDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/com.example.project/files");
    System.out.println (myFilesDir);
    myFilesDir.mkdirs();
}

public void TakePhoto(View v){
    Intent camIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    camIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(myFilesDir.toString()+"/temp.jpg")));
    startActivityForResult(camIntent, 0);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==0){
        try {
            Bitmap cameraBitmap;
            cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myFilesDir + "/temp.jpg");
            Bitmap.createBitmap(cameraBitmap);
            ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(cameraBitmap);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


}
```

Comment: If someone has given you the answer and you accept it you shouldn't answer your own question with the full code, with their answer included in it...

Answer (score 2):

Use my Code. I am taking a picture using camera intent and before saving it to gallery , it is showed to the user with a Save and Cancel Button :-
Call Camera Intent :-

```
                    String SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +CommonFunction.getDateTime()+".jpg"; // Get File Path
                    Intent takePictureFromCameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    takePictureFromCameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR)));
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureFromCameraIntent, 123);
```

onActivityResult : -

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_RESULT) 
        {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
            {
                String galleryImatePath = SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR; // make SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR Global so that you can access it here from camera intent or pass it in put Extra method and retrieve it here

                File f = new File(galleryImatePath);

                try {
                            Bitmap cameraBitmap = null;
                            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                            bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
                            bmOptions.inBitmap = cameraBitmap; 
                            bmOptions.inMutable = true; 


                            cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(galleryImatePath,bmOptions);
                            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            cameraBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);

                            //To Rotate image Code
                                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(galleryImatePath);
                                float rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);  
                                System.out.println(rotation);

                            float rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(rotation);
                            System.out.println(rotationInDegrees);

                            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                            matrix.postRotate(rotationInDegrees);

                            final Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cameraBitmap , 0, 0, cameraBitmap.getWidth(), cameraBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(galleryImatePath);
                            rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, fos);
                            fos.write(bos.toByteArray());
                            cameraBitmap.recycle();
                            System.gc();
                            fos.flush();
                            fos.close();


                            // To set image in imageview in dialog
                        Capdialog = new Dialog(AddToDo.this,android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
                        Capdialog.setContentView(R.layout.captiondialog);
                        Capdialog.setCancelable(false);
                        TextView cancel = (TextView) Capdialog
                                .findViewById(R.id.cancel);
                        TextView done = (TextView) Capdialog.findViewById(R.id.done);
                                                    Capdialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                        ImageView img = (ImageView) Capdialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                        img.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
                   }
                   catch(Exception e){}
          }
     }
}
```

implement your done and cancel on click listener - what you want to do in them.
My code will capture your image, rotate it in the right direction irrespective of camera rotation and show it to you in a dialog before saving it

Answer (score 1):

Google provided a tutorial on this exact topic: [Controlling the Camera](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html)

Comment: Thanks. I will be reading further into this. Too bad you can't just add parameters to disable saving to gallery :-/

Comment: @GarrenFitzenreiter Can't do parameters as the camera app would still need to write the image to someplace public for your app to pick it up as Intents were never made to transfer large data like images. Good luck.

Comment: I think what he wants is to stop the media scanner from showing it

Comment: @FabianCook Putting it in the non-media scannable directory on the SD card works too. He'll have to delete the picture from the SD card if he doesn't want storage to get cluttered and annoy the user.